# Qt, Dynamic allocation of memory

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a little question: I made a little program where every time the user click on a QPushButon a new object is created with his pointer, here is my code:

```
ajoute *az = new ajoute;
QVBoxLayout *layoutPrincipal = new QVBoxLayout;
```

the problem is that every object which have been created have the same name so if i want delete a object there probably will have a error ?

P.S : sorry for my bad english, i'm french

Comment: Missing some context over here. What is `ajoute`, and what do you do with the instances that you create?

Comment: am i right to say you only create the instances without putting them into a container or so?

Comment: Tried to draft an answer but definitely lacking context. For non french speaker "ajoute" means "add"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that every object which have been created have the same name so if i want delete a object there probably will have a error?

It seems like you are creating a group of dynamically allocated objects and you don't know how to store their pointers. The simplest way is to use a `QVector<ajoute*>` and store the dynamically allocated objects:

```
QVector<ajoute*> v;
```

Now whenever you create an `ajoute` you just do:

```
v.push_back( new ajoute );
```

That will add the pointer at the end of the vector (container). Then you can access them in order by doing:

```
v[0]; // first
v[1]; // second
v[2]; // third
```

And obviously you can delete them as:

```
delete v[0]; // example
```

Just remember to delete the pointer inside the vector as well:

```
v.remove(0);
```

Comment: Thank you it's a good idea, I think this is the answer I needed. So if I need to make an "ajoute" object attribute table I have to make a method that copies the value of "ajoute" attributes in for exemple QString variables which are in the main windows and creat another table in oder show and modify the "ajoute" object attributes ?

Comment: @DanSnow, what do you mean by "ajoute object attributes"?

Comment: thank you very much but I think I'll abandon the idea of creat object, i will use a simple container. if someone is interested I could pass him the beta version of my software for testing (it's a password manager).

Answer (score 2):

Your object is most probably on stack, so next instance will not "remember" about previous one. More code would be required to fine tune explanation.

Common solutions include :

- use an attribute (or many) in your class and delete before creating
- use QSharedPointer and reset pointed data (thus actually freeing previous instance)
- (Qt way) make object children of a "parent QObject" : it will be cascade-deleted when root of the objet tree is disposed of.

Comment: infact I did not yet made the program, I was just thinking how to do it.

Comment: infact I did not yet made the program, I was just thinking how to do it. The program works as it: 1-the user write a text in a QLineEdit 2-the text is stored in a variable  3-the "ajoute" object is created 4-the value of the variable is sent to the object "ajoute" 5-the "ajoute" object show a QLabel in a QVBoxLayout 6-another QLineEdit appears and the user can creat another "ajoute" object. It's like a chat

Comment: It looks like you're looking to store your string in a `QStringList` then have this list displayed in a `QListView` using a `QStringListModel` as adapter. I advise on reading http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html#view-classes

Comment: thank you :) I think I'll abandon the idea of creat object, i will use a simple container. if someone is interested I could pass him the beta version of my software for testing (it's a password manager).